# update fields from front-end

Tags: reactjs, sql-update, frontend, aws-serverless

I am trying to update fields (fullname, email, description) from the currently existing database. I am using serverless with react hooks (useEffect). I have put my api in another folder with "instance" object, so that on fetching the api, the code is:

```
const handleSubmit = (values) => {
instance.put("/user").then(values => {
  form.setFieldsValue({
    email: values.email,
    fullname: values.fullname,
    description: values.description,
  }).then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

where handleSubmit is a function being called on my form onFinish event.
And in the useEffect hook, the preset values for the user are given which are:

```
useEffect(() => {
form.setFieldsValue({
  email: auth.result.user.email,
  fullname: auth.result.user.fullname ? auth.result.user.fullname : "",
  description: auth.result.user.description
    ? auth.result.user.description
    : "",
});
handleSubmit();

}, []);
```

But, on completing the form, the user is not updating. **But, it is updating from backend, so the backend works fine. I just don't know how to update it from frontend** Kindly tell me if there is an error in the code.

Comment: In your useEffect() -> handleSubmit() expects an argument. It seems you are not passing any.

Comment: Yes i tried giving it "values" argument, but an error came saying that it is not defined

Comment: Try to pass hardcoded values to test. Something like handleSubmit({email:"email", fullname:"fname", description:"description"}).

Comment: Okay i will try this once my laptop is charged, will then respond to you

Comment: I tried this, this actually does nothing. On finishing the form, no changes in text fields is shown